# Effective way to track source deleted records in incremental load in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, incremental-load

Scenario :

1. The source is snowflake and it is in readonly mode.
2. Implementing full load, saving maximum timestamp in databricks for incremental load.
3. But in source side apart from record updates, records also being deleted and those records also need to be deleted from target(Databricks).
4. Note: dont want to do full load on regular basis as it is not effective.

Any helpful tips with example ?

Comment: Are you able to put a `STREAM` over your Snowflake table?  This would provide you with the incremental changes to the Snowflake table, including the deletes.  You could also just move your workloads into Snowpark and never have to move your data...ever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess STREAM option needs to implemented on snowflake side. I am not allowed to run anything on SF side. Currently i am reading sf data by using spark connector in databricks.

Comment: If you can’t do anything on the Snowflake side then the only solution would be to take the full table from Snowflake and compare it to the Databricks version. I would get someone to create the stream on Snowflake for you

Comment: Apologies for stealing the thread - `Off topic` - But with `STREAM` on snowflake, I was informed that once we read it, it is gone forever - so assume a unrealistic scenario of where the stream is read in my databricks notebook, processed and then loaded, In case there is a failure in the notebook during processing after the stream is read - the stream is gone forever right ? is there any way to have the stream data available as long as we confirm it has been loaded successfully ?

Comment: @rainingdistros “a stream advances its offset when it is used in a DML transaction”, not when it is read. For example, “insert into table select * from stream”. So just wrap all your processing in a transaction

Comment: @NickW Thank you for your response. Will this work in this scenario - Assume PYSPARK code run inside Databricks with SF conn `df = sf_conn_boilerplate.("SELECT * FROM STREAM") df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2)...` processing continues. If the processing fails, will the stream still be available in second or third run. What constitutes a transaction when Streams are called from spark i.e. outside Snowflake.

Comment: Please ask your own question

Comment: Agreed - https://stackoverflow.com/q/78218474/13280838 thank you...