# Safe way to read STREAMS from Snowflake within Databricks across retries

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks

We are exploring a scenario of reading snowflake streams data from within Azure Databricks.

Details:

- We have a large Snowflake table on which streams have been setup.
- We have other sources with which are accessible from Azure Databricks.
- Currently we are reading the entire table into a dataframe, performing processing within databricks and then loading to a file or table based on requirement.
- The design was made with the wrong assumption that the Streams data would be gone once it has been read.
- From a different question, I came to understand that Streams Data can be safely read across retries.

Question:

- How do we read Streams data safely from Databricks safely across retries ?

  - Assume below pyspark flow

    ```py
       df = # sf_conn_boilerplate.("SELECT * FROM STREAM") 
       df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2)
       # finally load to file
    ```
  - If streams is loaded to dataframe and fails in the subsequent steps, would it still be available for read in the subsequent retries ?

- What constitutes a transaction in Snowflake when accessed from external systems say databricks in this case

Thank you for your response.
Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

The "window" on a Stream is only advanced when the data in the Stream is used to update a target. So you can SELECT from a stream as many times as you want and you'll get the same data back. The data in the Stream will only change when you (or anyone else) executes statements that change data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, etc) and use the stream data. This is covered extensively in the documentation, with examples, [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro)

If your statements that change data are running exclusively in Databricks (and not against Snowflake) then what you run will have no impact on the Streams and the data will be available reagrdless of what runs or fails in Databricks. However, even if it runs successfully in Databricks, if you're not running a change DML statement in Snowflake the Stream will never advance and you'll never get an updated dataset when you query the Stream. Therefore, at some point you'd need to run a dummy change DML statement in Snowflake to advance the Stream